# Python Import Error when importing tests from django-social-auth

Tags: python, testing, import, django-socialauth

I'm trying to subclass some classes from the django-social-auth package to create custom test.

The source https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth

The problem is that i cannot import the "tests" part:

```
C:\Users\Alle>python
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84297, Aug 24 2010, 18:46:32) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import social_auth.tests.base
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named tests.base
>>> import social_auth.tests
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named tests
>>> import social_auth.db
>>> social_auth.db
<module 'social_auth.db' from 'C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\social_auth\db\__init__.pyc'>
>>>
```

why i get this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tests aren't installed by default

from social_auth [`setup.py`](https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth/blob/master/setup.py)

```
  packages=['social_auth',
            'social_auth.management',
            'social_auth.management.commands',
            'social_auth.backends',
            'social_auth.backends.contrib',
            'social_auth.backends.pipeline',
            'social_auth.migrations',
            'social_auth.db'],
```

Comment: ah! so to install them i have to change the packages in the setup?
this broke my install with pip

Comment: I don't know how to actually install them, i have little exp with setup.py i just see why they aren't installing:)